# Is there a way to make a graph chart with arrows using C# in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, series, mschart

I want to make a graph with 2 types of arrows (pointing up for the message received and down for the message sent, depending on the data it represents) with 2 different colors.

In particular, I have 2 type of string array which data are stored (message received, and message sent). These data are linked to the respective datetime arrays.

Here's an example:

Y AXIS:

```
RX_array = {MSG 10, MSG 11, MSG 12, ...}
TX_array = {MSG 13, MSG 14, MSG 15, ...}
```

X AXIS:

```
RX_Datetime_array= {2023.12.11_13.57.51, 2023.12.11_14.33.04, 2023.12.11_15.23.11, ...}
TX_Datetime_array= {2023.12.11_14.08.42, 2023.12.11_14.59.58, 2023.12.11_15.47.43, ...}
```

[Example image of the graph that I want to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ndI.png)

I tried searching on the web but couldn't find anything.
I tried using a dot chart but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think the mschart control supports that

Comment: Even if replacing the dots with images of arrows?

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem but I'm drowning  in deep blue. Can anyone help please?